# Java FXML key combination example wanted

Tags: javafx

I am building a calculator application in Java FXML. For more functionality aside from mouse clicking, I want to add keyboard key function so that user can type a number or a character on the keyboard to make them appear on calculator screen. I am using MacBookPro, in order to get + symbol I need to press key combination CMD and + keys. I tried the following way below, but it isn't working. Only **escape** and **backspace** keys are working very well. Even I just tried to check **back_slash** and **minus** keys, still they aren't working.

Can anybody help me how to create working key combinations only in **Java** **FXML** (which includes Main.java, Controller.java and FXMLDocument.fxml)

```
public class FXML_MainController implements Initializable {

KeyCombination plus = new KeyCodeCombination(KeyCode.PLUS, KeyCombination.SHORTCUT_DOWN);

@FXML
private Label displayTextBottom;

@FXML
void btnOnKeyPressed(KeyEvent event) {
    if (plus.match(event)) {
        displayTextBottom.setText(event.getText());
        System.out.println("+ pressed");
        event.consume();
    }

    switch (event.getCode()) {
        case SLASH:
            displayTextBottom.setText(event.getText());
            break;
        case MINUS:
            displayTextBottom.setText(event.getText());
            break;
        case ESCAPE:
            displayTextBottom.setText("");
            break;
        case BACK_SPACE:
            if (displayTextBottom.getText().length() > 0) {
                StringBuilder removing = new StringBuilder(displayTextBottom.getText());
                removing.deleteCharAt(displayTextBottom.getText().length() - 1);
                String removed = removing.toString();
                displayTextBottom.setText(removed);
                setDisplayFontSizeBottom();
            }
            break;

        default:
            System.out.println("error");
    }
}
```

Comment: who is `btnOnKeyPressed` in fxml?

Comment: It is tied to AnchorPane in fxml file like ... onKeyPressed="#btnOnKeyPressed"....

Answer (score 1):

**Replace SLASH to DIVIDE, MINUS to SUBTRACT and Change code in this way and try now.**

```
public class FXML_MainController implements Initializable {

        @FXML
        private Label displayTextBottom;

        final KeyCombination keyShiftPlus = new KeyCodeCombination(KeyCode.EQUALS, KeyCombination.SHIFT_ANY);
        final KeyCombination keyShiftMul = new KeyCodeCombination(KeyCode.DIGIT8, KeyCombination.SHIFT_ANY);
        final KeyCombination keyShiftDiv = new KeyCodeCombination(KeyCode.SLASH, KeyCombination.SHIFT_ANY);

    @FXML
    void btnOnKeyPressed(KeyEvent event) {

           if (keyShiftPlus.match(event) || event.getCode() == KeyCode.ADD) {
                field.setText("+");
                System.out.println("+ ADD");
                event.consume();
            }
            if (keyShiftMul.match(event) || event.getCode() == KeyCode.MULTIPLY) {
                field.setText("*");
                System.out.println("* Mul");
                event.consume();
            }
            if (keyShiftDiv.match(event) || event.getCode() == KeyCode.DIVIDE) {
                field.setText("/");
                System.out.println("/ Div");
                event.consume();
            }
            if (event.getCode() == KeyCode.MINUS || event.getCode() == KeyCode.SUBTRACT) {
                field.setText("-");
                System.out.println("- Minus");
            }

         switch (event.getCode()) {
            case DIVIDE:
                displayTextBottom.setText(event.getText());
                break;
            case SUBTRACT:
                displayTextBottom.setText(event.getText());
                break;
            case ESCAPE:
                displayTextBottom.setText("");
                break;
            case BACK_SPACE:
                if (displayTextBottom.getText().length() > 0) {
                    StringBuilder removing = new StringBuilder(displayTextBottom.getText());
                    removing.deleteCharAt(displayTextBottom.getText().length() - 1);
                    String removed = removing.toString();
                    displayTextBottom.setText(removed);
                    setDisplayFontSizeBottom();
                }
                break;

            default:
                System.out.println("error");
        }
    }
```

Comment: if you get any key code then print it in Console.for Ex: System.out.println(ke.getCode()); then use it.

Comment: Thank you Keyur. But how should I create key combinations like shift + a key and etc? If you know please give me an example in the controller class.

Comment: Well, code is working fine for KeyCode.A and other letters. But I still can't get ' + ', ' * ', ' / '. Note: I use MacBook, on which in order to get ' + ' and ' * '  shift + '+' and shift + '*' must be pressed together. Please, if you can, help me on this part of the problem.

Comment: @Ahmadali I have change code again try now,this code is work for both MacBook and desktop keybord.

Comment: @Ahmadali If you satisfied this answer then don't forgate to accept it.